# invoke bash function with user prompts from another function

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with a function that creates AWS instances. It calls another function that creates volumes and captures the output of that function in the calling function. The create volume function has user prompts.

In the create_instances function I has these lines that captures the output of create_volume:

```
create_instances() {
  ...lines to create the instance...
  printf "Number of volumes to add: "
  read -r num_volumes
  volumes=()
  for (( i=0; i < num_volumes; i++ )); do
    volumes[$i]="$(create_volume)"
      .... lines to attach volume...
   done

}
```

And no prompt appears on the screen like it would if you invoked create_volume separately.

In the create_volume function I have user prompts that asks for volume size, availability zone, volume name etc.  When create_instances calls this function to get the output, create_instances hangs and waits for user input. And you see nothing on the screen while this happens.

```
create_volume() {
    printf "Enter a volume name: "
    read -r volume_name

    #Availability Zones
    printf "Enter availability zone\\nExample. Type out: us-east-1a\\n"
    printf "AZ: "
    read -r availability_zone
    echo

    # Volume Size
    printf "Enter size: "
    read -r volume_size
    echo

    ...lines that create the volume...
    echo "$volume_id"
}
```

How can I capture the output of create_volume in the create_instances function and allow for the prompts that are needed in the create_volume function?

I need the prompts to appear when I use this pipeline: `volumes[$i]="$(create_volume)"`

Comment: Write your prompts to stderr, not stdout.

Comment: And if you want a function to run in the same shell instance -- as opposed to a subshell -- you need to use indirect assignment for your output, which `read` already does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `-p` option for `read` to set the prompt. That takes care of the rest:

```
create_volume() {
    local volume_name availability_zone volume_size
    read -rp "Enter a volume name: " volume_name
    read -rp $'Enter availability zone\nExample. Type out: us-east-1a\nAZ: ' availability_zone
    read -rp "Enter size: " volume_size

    # ...lines that create the volume...
    local volume_id="$volume_name,$availability_zone,$volume_size"
    echo ">>> $volume_id"
}
```

Interactively, the prompts are visible

```
$ create_volume
Enter a volume name: a
Enter availability zone
Example. Type out: us-east-1a
AZ: b
Enter size: c
>>> a,b,c
```

In a pipeline, they are not:

```
$ volume_id=$( printf '%s\n' foo bar baz | create_volume )
$ echo "$volume_id"
>>> foo,bar,baz
```

Comment: The create_volume function was prompting the user. But I need the prompts to appear when I invoke this pipeline: `volumes[$i]="$(create_volume)"` Is that not possible to do? Thanks

Comment: @bluethundr the `-p` option to `read` should take care of that, as @glenn said. It works for me, at least.

Comment: Very interesting. The -p prompt does prompt in the calling function (create_instances) from the called function (create_volume). But what I see is `volume_size` from the line:`read -rp volume_size` in create_volume. But what I need is the prompt line to appear in the calling function: ` printf "Enter size: ". Is there any way to do that from the calling function (create_instances)?

Comment: You forgot the argument to `-p`: `read -rp "Enter size: " volume_size` -- what you have is `read -rp volume_size` where the prompt is the string "volume_size" and the value goes into the default variable `$REPLY`